# Android - difference between offsetTopAndBottom, setTranslateY

Tags: android, android-view

Android [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) seems to have 2 methods which appears to do some very similar functionality.

1] `setTranslationX` & `setTranslationY`
2] `offsetLeftAndRight` & `offsetTopAndBottom`

Can anybody tell me how these are different?
What is the scenarion in which [1] can be used but not [2]? and vise-versa?

Answer (score 9):

`offsetLeftAndRight()` and `offsetTopAndBottom()` alter the result of the layout pass, while `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY` add an additionnal offset on top of the layout result, the default value being 0.

One consequence is that the leftAndRight / TopAndBottom offset is reset with every layout pass (e.g. triggered by `requestLayout()`) while the translation is not.

My understanding is that `offsetLeftAndRight()` and `offsetTopAndBottom()` are mostly useful if you write your own Layout, while `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY` are generic methods to tweak the result of a layout.

Answer (score -2):

in normal terms both functions are a product of different api levels , now in settranslation the api should be atlest 16, but for offset u can see them from quiet earlier    api, and the difference between both is , settranslationx and y , gives us an effect of moving the screen ,does not require aplha in it, but for offset its a blurring function where  the alpha is the key point, 
the settranslate example

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

, will create an illution of moving the screen left to right 
where offset

```
<offset AlphaAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromalpha="0.0f"  android:toalpha=1.0f"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

will create a blurring UI

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590664/what-does-offsetleftandright-exactly-do) offsetTopAndBottom is not same as what you say.