# What's the difference about the result of a call to view's offsetTopAndBottom and setTranslateY?

Tags: android, animation, view

Internally, both **mTop** and **translateY** determines the view's position along with the **Y-axis**, which one should be chosen when animating a view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - difference between offsetTopAndBottom, setTranslateY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196553/android-difference-between-offsettopandbottom-settranslatey)

Comment: @Pawel thanks, the answer explains that these two attributes can take effect together, but which to choose when I want to animating a view on y-axis, is there any sutle performance considerations?